# how to store JSON list data into python variables?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, list

I have a JSON file that contains some data.
testJSON.json

```
{
"hourlyData": [
    {
        "frequency": "49.96",
        "actual": " 2,240.43 ",
        "schedule": " 2,223.85 ",
        "acp": "325"
    },
    {
        "frequency": "50.04",
        "actual": " 1,862.88 ",
        "schedule": " 1,881.09 ",
        "acp": "275"
    },
    {
        "frequency": "50.04",
        "actual": " 1,882.17 ",
        "schedule": " 1,885.94 ",
        "acp": "275"
    }
  ],
"storageData": [
    {
        "config": "ESS1",
        "name": "BRPL",
        "Power Rating": "20",
        "Energy Rating": "20",
        "socLow": "0",
        "socHigh": "0.8",
        "Charge Eff": "0.9273",
        "Discharge Eff": "0.9273",
        "Round Trip Eff": "0.922",
        "Lower Limit": "57",
        "Mid Limit": "76",
        "High Limit": "95",
        "Thrushold": "5",
        "Discharging Price": "6"
    }
],
```

I want to store these values into python variables. So what I have done is that first I created a dictionary which contain different variables of different types then I created a function which simple opens the JSON file then I try to store those json values into declared variables:
test.py

```
import json
#decalaring variables 
storageData = {
    "name": 'No name specified',
    "powerRating":-1,
    "energyRating":-1,
    "annualMaxCycles":365,
    "socLow":-1,
    "socHigh":-1,
    "chargeEff":-1,
    "dChargeEff":-1,
    "lowerLimit": -1,
    "midLimit": -1,
    "highLimit": -1,
    "thrushold": 5,
    "dischargingPrice": 6
}
marketData = {
    "marketProducts": {
            "dsm":{
            "frequency":[],
            "schedule":[],
            "actual":[],
            "acp": [],
            }
          }
inputMode = 'JSON'
JSONfileName = "testJSON.json"

def inputJSON():
  if (inputMode == 'JSON'):
    fileName = JSONfileName
    # Import data from JSON files
    with open(JSONfileName, 'r') as myfile:
      dataJSON = ((myfile.read().replace('\n', '')))
    inputJSON = json.loads(dataJSON)

    # Assigning the storageData data
    storageData['powerRating'] = inputJSON['storageData']['Power Rating']
    storageData['energyRating'] = inputJSON['storageData']['energyRating']
    storageData['warranty'] = inputJSON['storageData']['powerRating']
    storageData['annualMaxCycles'] = inputJSON['storageData']['maxAnnualCycles']
    storageData['socLow'] = inputJSON['storageData']['socLow']
    storageData['socHigh'] = inputJSON['storageData']['socHigh']
    storageData['chargeEff'] = inputJSON['storageData']['chargeEff']
    storageData['dChargeEff'] = inputJSON['storageData']['dChargeEff']
    storageData['lowerLimit'] = inputJSON['storageData']['lowerLimit']
    storageData['midLimit'] = inputJSON['storageData']['midLimit']
    storageData['highLimit'] = inputJSON['storageData']['highLimit']
    storageData['thrushold'] = inputJSON['storageData']['thrushold']
    storageData['dischargingPrice'] = inputJSON['storageData']['dischargingPrice']

    marketData['marketProducts']['dsm']['frequency'] = inputJSON['hourlyData']['frequency']
    marketData['marketProducts']['dsm']['acp'] = inputJSON['hourlyData']['acp']
    marketData['marketProducts']['dsm']['actual'] = inputJSON['hourlyData']['actual']
    marketData['marketProducts']['dsm']['schedule'] = inputJSON['hourlyData']['schedule']

inputJSON()
```

error that it gives me

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/nvats/PycharmProjects/dsm-final/test2.py", line 113, in <module>
    inputJSON()
  File "C:/Users/nvats/PycharmProjects/dsm-final/test2.py", line 80, in inputJSON
    storageData['powerRating'] = inputJSON['storageData']['Power Rating']
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Comment: `storage_data = inputJSON['storageData'][0]` and the use it.

Comment: Look at your json file, "storageData" is an array not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
# Assigning the storageData data
storageData['powerRating'] = inputJSON['storageData']['Power Rating']
storageData['energyRating'] = inputJSON['storageData']['energyRating']
storageData['warranty'] = inputJSON['storageData']['powerRating']
storageData['annualMaxCycles'] = inputJSON['storageData']['maxAnnualCycles']
storageData['socLow'] = inputJSON['storageData']['socLow']
storageData['socHigh'] = inputJSON['storageData']['socHigh']
storageData['chargeEff'] = inputJSON['storageData']['chargeEff']
storageData['dChargeEff'] = inputJSON['storageData']['dChargeEff']
storageData['lowerLimit'] = inputJSON['storageData']['lowerLimit']
storageData['midLimit'] = inputJSON['storageData']['midLimit']
storageData['highLimit'] = inputJSON['storageData']['highLimit']
storageData['thrushold'] = inputJSON['storageData']['thrushold']
storageData['dischargingPrice'] = inputJSON['storageData']['dischargingPrice']
```

Do

```
 # Assigning the storageData data
storageData['powerRating'] = inputJSON['storageData[0]']['Power Rating']
storageData['energyRating'] = inputJSON['storageData[0]']['energyRating']
storageData['warranty'] = inputJSON['storageData[0]']['powerRating']
storageData['annualMaxCycles'] = inputJSON['storageData[0]']['maxAnnualCycles']
storageData['socLow'] = inputJSON['storageData[0]']['socLow']
storageData['socHigh'] = inputJSON['storageData[0]']['socHigh']
storageData['chargeEff'] = inputJSON['storageData[0]']['chargeEff']
storageData['dChargeEff'] = inputJSON['storageData[0]']['dChargeEff']
storageData['lowerLimit'] = inputJSON['storageData[0]']['lowerLimit']
storageData['midLimit'] = inputJSON['storageData[0]']['midLimit']
storageData['highLimit'] = inputJSON['storageData[0]']['highLimit']
storageData['thrushold'] = inputJSON['storageData[0]']['thrushold']
storageData['dischargingPrice'] = inputJSON['storageData[0]']['dischargingPrice']
```

Because it's an array, whose 1st index has the json data.

Ex. for "hourlyData"

```
for(data of inputJSON['hourlyData']){
    marketData['marketProducts']['dsm']['frequency'] = data['frequency']
}
```

---

Hope that helps.

Comment: can you please be more specific? storageData is a dictionary which contains different variables like powerRating, energyRating etc. I want to store json data into these variables.

Comment: Edited my answer. Sorry I didn't understand it at first.

Comment: this works partially. for the storageData variables, it is working but for the hourlyData values, when I try to store frequency, acp, actual and schedule values into marketData variables then it is also showing error.

Comment: you have to make a "for loop" that will take all indexes of the "hourlyData". As its also an array but with multiple indexes

Comment: Ex.` for(data of hourlyData){marketData['marketProducts']['dsm']['frequency'] = inputJSON['hourlyData']['frequency']}`

Comment: there is one problem. I am able to store all the JSON data into the variables but when I try to access them it shows error. for example:     for i, j, in zip(marketData['marketProducts']['dsm']['schedule'], marketData['marketProducts']['dsm']['actual']):
        dev = j - i
        print(dev)